# Redirect to Login page after session time out in spring mvc 4.2 without spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the interceptor which checks

```
if (null ==session) {           
        response.sendRedirect("redirect:/login");            
        return false;
    }
```

and my controller method for login.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginUser(
         @ModelAttribute("admin") ValidateAdmin dmin) {
    System.out.println("Loading login method");
    return "login";
}
```

but its not redirecting to the controller login method if the session time expires. Not found any conclusive answer in many of the posts.
I want to redirect user to login page after session expires and user hits any of the mapped controllers.

Answer (score 1):

If the session has expired, a new one is created so it ll never be null in your interceptor.

Since you use a custom login you should put an attribute in the session like 'login' = 'ok'

Then in your interceptor, if there no such attribute in the session it means that the user is not logged in (because he is new or his session has expired) and you can redirect him to the login page.